# Access a model through an intermediate relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to retrieve the model `games` using the `giveaway` model

```
giveaway:
id

giveaway_games:
id
gameID
giveawayID

games:
id
name
```

Reading the docummentation I understood I have to use the `hasManyThrough` relationship but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly

```
public function gamesNames(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Games::class, GiveawayGames::class, 'gameID', 'id');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `games` table need a foreign key to `giveaway_games`. In the following example I stick to Laravel default using `_id` suffix for foreign key fields.

**Class**:

```
class GiveAway 
{
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Games::class, GiveawayGames::class);
    }
}
```

> As a mnemonic you could read the `hasManyThrough` as:
>
> *GiveAway* has many *Games* through *GiveawayGames*
>
> or more abstract:
>
> *Model* has many *Parameter 1* through *Parameter 2*

---

**Schema**:

giveaway:

- id
- name

giveaway_games:

- id
- giveaway_id

games:

- id
- name
- giveaway_games_id

---

**Note for custom names for foreign keys:**

If you are forced to customize the name of the foreign key like using `giveawayID` instead of `giveaway_id`, you can specify the custom name as the 3rd parameter of the `hasManyThrough()` method:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Games::class, GiveawayGames::class, 'giveawayID');
```

If you additionally customized the name of the `id` field, lets say to `uuid` you can specify this in the 4th parameter:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Games::class, GiveawayGames::class, 'giveawayID', 'uuid');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Just a quick note that I think will improve the answer. I have used this: `return $this->hasManyThrough(Games::class, GiveawayGames::class, 'giveawayID', 'id');` which I think will help future people having the same problem

Comment: I noticed that. Are you beeing forced (by name schema or somthing else) to not stick to Laravels naming conventions?

Comment: It was a bad practice that I have used in others projects and I got get rid of. Specially in Laravel since they have a convention for that